# Get back this string to html with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I confused how to get back this string to HTML,

```
<h2><span style=\\\"color: #ff6600;\\\">sgsag<\/span><\/h2>
```

I want get like this;

```
<h2><span style="color: #ff6600;">sgsag</span></h2>
```

Please help/.

Comment: `innerHTML` using you can do directly

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to do anything special; just use **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** and the browser will automatically parse the backslashes:

```js
var string = '<h2><span style=\\\"color: #ff6600;\\\">sgsag<\/span><\/h2>';
var target = document.getElementById('target');
target.innerHTML = string;
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How to place it on textarea

Comment: with jQuery, it just `$('#target').html(string);`

Comment: if like this <code><h2><span style=\"color: #ff6600;\">bfbfb</span></h2></code>, how to remove slash

Comment: @Opsional I have posted a new answer for that case, please see below

Comment: @Opsional -- Either add an ID to the `<textarea>` (recommended), or target the `<textarea>` element with `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]`. You'd need the `[0]` in that case because `getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList collection of elements, and you want the (presumably) first index.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution suing jQuery

```js
$('body').html("<h2><span style=\\\"color: #ff6600;\\\">sgsag<\/span><\/h2>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've used `.html`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var string = "<h2><span style=\\\"color: #ff6600;\\\">sgsag<\/span><\/h2>";
var content = string.replace(/\\/g, '');
$('textarea').val(content);
```